# Switching http to https using mod_rewrite

Tags: http, mod-rewrite, https

I know there are lots of similar questions, but I spent more than 2 days investigating it with no success, so you are my last hope )

I wrote following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^((/member/settings)?/orders/?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|eot|woff|ttf|svg)$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^((/member/settings)?/orders/?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I want URLs `example.com/orders/` and `example.com/member/settings/orders/` always redirect to HTTPS, and all others force using HTTP. Also all queries should be forward to `index.php`.
And, obviously, all media files should stay in same protocol as they was requested.

When I'm requesting `http://example.com/orders/` first it redirects to `https://example.com/orders/`, but then redirects second time to `http://example.com/index.php?/orders/` . What actually is expected, but problem is that 'index.php' appears in browser's address bar.

The question is how to get rid of 'index.php' in browser's address bar?

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> then redirects second time to http://example.com/index.php?/orders/ .... I have no idea from where 'index.php' comes up in URL...

Because you have a RewriteRule to do just that:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish in that block, but try getting rid of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need all requests be executed in index.php that's why I need that rule. Problem is that 'index.php' appear in browser's address bar.